# Drawing line between one point and another

Tags: android, drawing, point

I have a custom line view between a center button and 12 outer buttons, see pic.
Code block 1 is what I use to get the center points of each button combination.
Code block 2 is my 'custom drawing' , which draws the line between each set of center points, 12 lines in total.
The 12 custom lines are all inside an xml file.
The buttons and lines are passed into Public Class Drawline as in two separate arrays.

I've also created a class that uses Path to draw a triangle.  this is sitting in the upper left hand corner of my graphic.

What I want.

A line  between the centers of the buttons that stops short of the second end point.
I want the line between the points to end as you see between the buttons 'crispy crunchy' and 'balance'. I need help finding how to 'get' the x,y of this point.     I also what to put the arrowhead on the end of the line.

[image]

```
public class Drawline {
    public void drawLines(List<LineView> mlinesToDraw,ArrayList<Button> buttonsbalance, Context
            context,Button btnbase) {
        float centerXOnImage1;
        double centerYOnImage1;
        float centerXOfImageOnScreen1;
        double centerYOfImageOnScreen1;
        float centerXOnImage2;
        float centerYOnImage2;
        float centerXOfImageOnScreen2;
        float centerYOfImageOnScreen2;
        List<LineView> mLine = mlinesToDraw;
        ArrayList<Button> btns = buttonsbalance;
        PointF pointA;
        PointF pointB;

        for (int i = 0; i < mLine.size(); i++) {
            Button button1 = btns.get(i + 1);  //skip btnx0/btnbase
            centerXOnImage1 = button1.getWidth() / 2;
            centerYOnImage1 = (button1.getHeight()) / 2;//-actionBarHeight)/2;
            centerXOfImageOnScreen1 = button1.getLeft()+ centerXOnImage1;
            centerYOfImageOnScreen1 = button1.getTop() + (centerYOnImage1);

            Button button2 = btnbase;
            centerXOnImage2 = button2.getWidth() / 2;
            centerYOnImage2 = (button2.getHeight()) / 2;//-actionBarHeight)/2;
            centerXOfImageOnScreen2 = button2.getLeft() + centerXOnImage2;
            centerYOfImageOnScreen2 = button2.getTop() + (centerYOnImage2);

            pointA = new PointF(centerXOfImageOnScreen1, (float) centerYOfImageOnScreen1);
            pointB = new PointF(centerXOfImageOnScreen2, (float) centerYOfImageOnScreen2);

            mLine.get(i).setPointA(pointA);
            mLine.get(i).setPointB(pointB);
            mLine.get(i).draw();
        }
    }
```

Custom drawing class.

```
public class LineView extends View {
   private Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
   private PointF pointA,pointB;

//    private void init() {
//        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
//    }

    public LineView(Context context) {
        super(context);
     //   init();
    }

    public LineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
     //   init();
    }

    public LineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
       // init();
    }
    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int color = R.color.GradientStart;
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
         paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
         canvas.drawLine(pointA.x, pointA.y, pointB.x, pointB.y, paint);
    }
    public void setPointA(PointF point){
            pointA=point;}
    public void setPointB(PointF point){
        pointB=point;}

    public void draw(){
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }}
```

I feel like there should be an easier way to do this but I've not found it yet.
I appreciate any help. 
thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Because I now the angle of each outer button and the radius to the point, I was able to get the location using polar coordinates. I then used the following conversion to get the corresponding x and y coordinates.

val x = radius * Math.cos(angle);
val y = radius * Math.sin(angle);

This gave me the alternate endpoint I needed to draw the line.